# Requirement of installation of the latest LTS version

Tags: hardware, compatibility

Can I use the latest LTS version of ubuntu with a celeron processor and 512 MB ram?
If the answer is positive then how?
I'm now using 12.04 LTS version of ubuntu..

Answer (score 1):

**A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.**

[Ubuntu minimal requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) are as follows:

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Internet access is helpful
```

Screen resolution will be set at the highest your graphics card can handle but when you boot-up you should be given a "Low graphics mode" option which allows you to set it to something better for your monitor.

On one hand, hardware produced in the last few years or with an efficient architecture or machines built for a specific purpose can often work well with less. For example, a netbook with an 8 GB SSD will work well although there wont be much room for saving stuff directly onto the drive so cloud storage services could help a lot. A machine with a crumbling, 15 year-old, slow, 8 GB, IDE hard-drive probably won't work and doesn't really compare with the netbook anyway. It might be worth trying Ubuntu but really start looking at other distros. On the other hand, some GNU/Linux distributions may require more powerful hardware as minimum system requirements, like the Ubuntu GNOME case.

All 64-bit (x86-64) CPUs should be fast enough to run Ubuntu and can run the 32-bit (x86) version as well. For an optimized installation (and especially for those wishing to run more than ~3 GiB of RAM) however, a 64-bit installation CD is available. The 32-bit version tends to be easier to use and runs into less problems.

Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and up uses Unity as the default GUI while the previous releases used GNOME Panel by default. In order to run Unity the system needs a more capable graphics adapter – see more here or below:

- 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB

From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB RAM to properly run a day to day Ubuntu.

**A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.**